# Change Elastic Beanstalk Platform Python version

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been having troubles deploying my application with Elastic Beanstalk. I need to change the platform I am using to a current one that is accepted. I am using python 3.10.6 in my project so I am completely unsure of where the version 2.6 came from.

[image: Elastic Beanstalk status]

Comment: Sadly your question is unclear and lacks details. Please explain better what is happening and what do you want to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Major python upgrade can't be done by simple changing a setting. You are also running Amazon Linux instead of Amazon Linux 2. Upgrading to python 3 would mean for you that you need to migrate to a new EB environment.

You need to migrate your application:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration.html

I suspect you need to upgrade to Amazon Linux 2 aswell. There are alot of differences between how you need to configure your application. When I did this upgrade, I needed to rewrite alot of my existing configuration.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html